# Properties of proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am pretty sure I missed some of the basic properties of proportions.

I am working with positive rational numbers. If we know that $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{e}{f}=\dfrac{g}{h}$, can we say $\dfrac{e}{f}=\dfrac{a+g}{b+h}$? Thank you in advance! How can we summarise this property if it's true?

Comment: Watch out for the possibility that $a=-g$ and so $b=-h$

Comment: I assume you are working with positive rational numbers.  It helps to consider one of these written in simplest form.  Suppose without loss of generality that $\frac{c}{d}$ is written in simplest form.  Then $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{kc}{kd}$ for some integer $k$.  Similarly $\frac{e}{f}=\frac{\ell c}{\ell d}$ for some integer $\ell$ and so on...

Comment: Did you test this equality with any specific values?

Comment: Yes, I did! It works.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang you seem to be reaching for a counterexample when none exists (*except for 0 divided by 0 cases which careful wording of the property will avoid*)

Comment: I am not searching for a counterexample! I am just asking if this is true.

Comment: @JMoravitz you're right; I thought I had one but now I see why it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the "*Componendo theorem of proportions*", which allows for a quick way to perform ratio calculations.

To prove, you simply take $\dfrac{a}{g}+1=\dfrac{b}{h}+1$ and then rearrange.

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{e}{f}=\frac{g}{h}$ then

$\frac{e}{f}=\frac{a+g}{b+h}$

Because

$\frac{e}{f}=\frac{a+g}{b+h}\Leftrightarrow eb+eh=fa+fg$

As $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{e}{f}$ we have $fa=be$

$\frac{e}{f}=\frac{g}{h}$ we have $eh=fg$,

Hence $eb+eh=fa+fg$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my hint above...

Consider things written in simplest form.  Without loss of generality, assume $\frac{c}{d}$ is in simplest form.

That means that there are some integers $k,\ell,m$ such that $a=kc,b=kd,~e=\ell c,f=\ell d,~g=mc,h=md$

So, the ratio we are interested in can be rewritten as $\dfrac{a+g}{b+h}=\dfrac{kc+mc}{kd+md}=\dfrac{(k+m)c}{(k+m)d}$

Which one can see does indeed equal $\dfrac{c}{d}$ and thus $\dfrac{e}{f}$ as well by whatever standard argument one might choose.

---

By examining the argument one can modify it slightly to work for arbitrary real numbers as well, the only dangerous condition that one needs to watch out for is if you had $a+g=b+h=0$ as this would have resulted in a zero divided by zero error.